# Efficient implementation of quick select algorithm on GPU?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, nvidia

I am wondering if there is an efficient implementation of the quick select algorithm on the GPU. I hope to use the implementation to find the kth largest element. If there is none, I will write my own. But was wondering if something already exists?

Answer (score 1):

Sean Baxter started to take a crack at it on moderngpu.com: http://www.moderngpu.com/select/mgpuselect.html

Comment: software: I thought mgpuselect using radix select, not quick select. He even says that quick select is not fit for GPU????